# Chebyshev approximation for bivariate function

Tags: approximation, approximation-theory, chebyshev-polynomials, multivalued-functions

I read the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2302.11139).
I am a litte bit confused regarding formulation of Chebyshev approximation for bivariate function(See photo). There is only one integral over variable x. Should it be in formula one  more additonal integral over variable y?

I found another source where integration was over both variables

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zix5C.png)

Thank you for the help!